# StringComparer не работает в Join Linq

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq

Мне нужно сцепить два массива `string[]` по совпадению без учета регистра и с учетом регистра.

Вычитал здесь вот такую конструкцию:

```
var sql = s.Join(p, str => s, 
pet => p, 
(str, pet) => new { Base = str, IsExists = pet != null }, 
StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Но шутка в том что компилятор на весь Join орёт:
*Ошибка CS0411  Аргументы типа для метода "Enumerable.Join<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(IEnumerable<TOuter>, IEnumerable<TInner>, Func<TOuter, TKey>, Func<TInner, TKey>, Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult>, IEqualityComparer<TKey>)" не могут определяться по использованию. Попытайтесь явно определить аргументы типа.*

Убираю `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` и не ругается. А мне сравнение по регистру важно.

Я уже и явно типы определил,

```
s.Join<string, string, string[], ListWordsExists>
(p, 
str => s, 
pet => p, 
(str, pet) => new ListWordsExists { Base = str, IsExists = pet != null },
StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

а он в меня другой заразой плюется:
*Ошибка CS1929  'string[]" не содержит определение для "Join", и наиболее подходящий перегруженный метод расширения "Queryable.Join<string, string, string[], ListWordsExists>(IQueryable<string>, IEnumerable<string>, Expression<Func<string, string[]>>, Expression<Func<string, string[]>>, Expression<Func<string, string, ListWordsExists>>, IEqualityComparer<string[]>)" требует наличия получателя типа "IQueryable<string>".*

Чего он от меня хочет я не понимаю. Всё же указано. Где я не прав?

Comment: какие типы у `s`, и `p`?

Comment: судя по всему вместо `str => s, 
pet => p` нужно `str => str, 
pet => pet`

Comment: @Grundy это сработало... Но почему? Как это можно было понять? Какая тут логика?...(

Comment: очень простая, смотри на типы, например, `Func<TOuter, TKey>` по одному типу, здесь `TOuter` у тебя string, а `TKey` - ты возвращал `string[]`, следовательно и компарер должен был быть для массивов, а ты пытался вставить компарер для строк